# How to show object keys in an HTML table with VueJS2?

Tags: vuejs2

How can I get the keys of a JSON object and display them in my `<th>` section of the below hTML table?

For example, I have a JSON object:

`myData.JSON`:

```
{ "entryType": 2, "name": "JOHN", "name_old": "JOHNNY", "shortName": "Jonny", "shortName_old": "Jon" }
```

Then, I have the HTML table like so:

```
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Field</th>
              <th>{{ myData.name }}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, index) in myData" :key="index">
              <th>XXX___how to put the object keys here?___XXX</th>
              <td>{{ value}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [VUEJS2 docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object), I was able to get what I needed with:

```
                <tr
                  v-for="(value, keyName, index) in filteredFields"
                  :key="index"
                >
                  <th>
                    {{ keyName }}
                  </th>
                  <td>{{ value }}</td>
```